# Binding SSL certificates to Website in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I have a server which is hosting a domain named abc.com . I have an SSL certificate installed for this domain on server and abc.com require SSL. Now I have a sub domain say sub.abc.com which is secured by another SSL certificate.

Now this is what I did to bind. Clicked the main site abc.com in IIS and opened bindings. Now in bindings, I added https and for IP Address I gave All Unassigned. For SSL certificate I selected the SSL cert for abc.com.

Again for the sub domain binding I followed same steps but under IP Address I gave the IP (19.xxx.xx.xx) of my server. Under certificate I picked the certificate for sub.abc.com.

Now on a browser if I open sub.abc.com its working fine. But if I load abc.com then the site is loading with warning and its displaying the certificate of sub.abc.com instead of abc.com . In bindings I can confirm that I have mapped to correct certificate.

Not sure whats going wrong here. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running IIS 8 and above, you can use SNI,

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Comment: Thanks for this. I am running IIS 7.5, does that mean I need to have separate IP for each sub domain secured with SSL?

Comment: @Zach even if you can get separate IP addresses, SSL bindings are not easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You may also go for WildCard certificate i.e a certificate issues to *.abc.com for the root domain , this will not only simplify your deployment and will provide adequate security as well.